# Apache Hive: How to convert string to timestamp?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, emr

I'm trying to convert the string in `REC_TIME` column to a timestamp format in hive.

Ex: *Sun Jul 31 09:28:20 UTC 2016 **=>** 2016-07-31 09:28:20*

```
SELECT xxx, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(REC_TIME, "E M dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy") FROM wlogs LIMIT 10;
```

When I execute the above SQL it returns a NULL value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("Sun Jul 31 09:28:20 UTC 2016","EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"));
```

This works fine if your hive cluster has UTC timezone. Say suppose your server is in CST then you need to do as below to get to UTC;

```
select to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("Sun Jul 31 09:28:20 UTC 2016","EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy")),'CST');
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Hive date functions use the JAVA simple date formater for the patterns . Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the patterns.

Comment: Thanks Nidhin, this worked. Can you share the docs link for this if i have to do more manipulation with the timestamps? it would be helpful

Comment: Added the reference URL. Appreciate if you could accept the answer if the answer , answered the question.

Comment: What if my server is in EST and converts it into GMT. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware my computers runs on PDT

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ date +%Z
PDT
```

So the UTC time is converted to 2:28:20 PDT. Anyway this is not the point.
You are using HH for hours, use hh and you need at least 3 M for the month.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://quickstart:10000/default> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("Sun Jul 31 09:28:20 UTC 2016", 'E MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy')) as date;
+----------------------+--+
|         date         |
+----------------------+--+
| 2016-07-31 02:28:20  |
+----------------------+--+
```